# Python - Convert array with list with different sizes to string

Tags: python

I have a Python array that contains a lot of lists, with different sizes.

```
myArray = [('Hello my name is ', ('Bond, James', 'Bond. It is ', '16:40', ' now'), '!!!')]
```

**Question:** What is the best way (more optimized) to get the bellow output, without creating a loop method which will append every value to a string?

I would like to see the following output:

```
"Hello my name is Bond, James Bond. It is 16:40 now!!!"
```

Comment: What do you mean "without creating a loop?" Do you strictly want to do this recursively, and if so, why? Or would e.g. a list comprehension be fine, too?

Comment: without explicitly creating a for i in myArray, etc... there should be an easier way, I guess :)

Comment: Restricting the use of language elements rarely makes something easier.

Comment: maybe using numpy ... but I'm not familiar with that, and I didn't find any useful answer on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to flatten the nested list to a 'flat' list. Assuming that your list contains either strings or other lists (or tuples), you could use a function like this:

```
def flatten(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, str):
            yield x
        else:
            for y in flatten(x):
                yield y
```

Incidentally, there also seems to be a function for this in the `compiler.ast` module, so alternatively you could just import that function and use it. However, this module is deprecated and has been removed in Python 3.

```
from compiler.ast import flatten
```

Either way, after the list has been flattened, you just have to join the segments to one string.

```
>>> list(flatten(myArray))
['Hello my name is ', 'Bond, James', 'Bond. It is ', '16:40', ' now', '!!!']
>>> ''.join(flatten(myArray))
'Hello my name is Bond, JamesBond. It is 16:40 now!!!'
```

Comment: this is what I need :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a very comprehensive recursive function like the one I wrote -

```
In [1]: def solve(x):
            if isinstance(x, str):
                return x
            return ''.join(solve(y) for y in x)

In [2]: solve(myArray)
Out[2]: 'Hello my name is Bond, JamesBond. It is 16:40 now!!!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation which joins as it flattens:

```
def deepJoin(stuff,d = ' '):
    if isinstance(stuff,str):
        return stuff
    else:
        return d.join(deepJoin(x,d) for x in stuff)
```

For example:

```
>>> deepJoin( [('Hello my name is ', ('Bond, James', 'Bond. It is ', '16:40', ' now'), '!!!')])
'Hello my name is  Bond, James Bond. It is  16:40  now !!!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a list comprehension to flatten the list:

```
bond_says = ["".join(item) for sublist in myArray for item in sublist] # list comprehension
print(" ".join(bond_says))
```

Output:

```
"Hello my name is  Bond, JamesBond. It is 16:40 now !!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex (python 2.7):

```
import re
myArray = [('Hello my name is ', ('Bond, James', 'Bond. It is ', '16:40', ' now'), '!!!')]
print re.sub("(?:^|')[^']+(?:'|$)", '',str(myArray))

[Output]

Hello my name is Bond, JamesBond. It is 16:40 now!!!
```

**UPDATE**

*Try this with myArray= [('Won\'t work with this.')] – tobias_k 7 hours ago*

```
import re
p = r"(?:^|(?<!\\)')[^'\"\\]+(?:'|$)|(?:^|\")[^\"]+(?:\"|$)"

myArray = [('Hello my name is ', ('Bond, James', 'Bond. It is ', '16:40', ' now'), '!!!')]
myArray2= [('Won\'t work with this.')]

print (re.sub(p, '', str(myArray)))
print (re.sub(p, '', str(myArray2)))

[Output]

Hello my name is Bond, JamesBond. It is 16:40 now!!!
Won't work with this.
```

Comment: Try this with `myArray= [('Won\'t work with this.')]`

Comment: Updated with a new pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A `map` makes it pretty concise:

```
def flatten(arr):
    if type(arr) == str:
        return arr.strip()
    else:
        return " ".join(map(flatten, arr))
```

returns "Hello my name is Bond, James Bond. It is 16:40 now !!!" for the example.

Comment: Why not `if type(arr) == str`?